# How do I bind a custom class to the entire page in winrt xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

I am trying to bind a complex custom object to an entire xaml page.
How do I achieve this? I've tried assigning it to the pages DataContext but that is not working.

Sample code:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter != null)
    {
        currentParameter = e.Parameter as ParameterObject;
        currentResultObject = await ProcessStaticClass.getTheResult(currentParameter);

        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () =>
        {
            this.Frame.DataContext = currentResultObject 
        });
    }
}
```

And my xaml is :

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" >
  <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Object1.Content}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Object2.Content}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Object4.Content}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Please note this is just a sample my objects are more complex and xaml is also nested/complex.

How to bind this?

Comment: Your binding looks strange... I think that's the problem. In your code you bind to the Content property of the Object1 property of your currentResultObject. 

If your datacontext is something like this: class MyDataContext{ public string Content{get; set; }} then your binding is just  Text="{Binding Content}". I would first look into this direction. Btw you see this in the output window when you debug the code

Comment: But my currentResultObject contains a Object1 member which is again a class and contains Content as a string. Shouldn't I specify the hierarchy. I'm not able to debug as there are no binding errors displayed

Comment: Well, ok in this case the problem is somewhere else... what about this.Frame.DataContext? Why setting it on the frame and not directly on this.DataContext?

Comment: Yeah first I tried that but neither works :(

Comment: I'm out of ideas... do you have a small reproducer?

Comment: Now its working I'm not sure what the issue was just cleaned the project

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please show the code of your `ProcessStaticClass`, I'm kind of confused what were you doing.